# Evaluate $f'(x)$ as a function of $x$ where $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(xy)}{y}~dy$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $x > 0$. Define
>   $$f(x)  = \int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{\sin(xy)}{y}~dy$$
>   Evaluate $f'(x)$ as a function of $x$. where $f'(x)$ denotes the derivative of the function $f$.

My attempts ;  i was using the leibnitz theorem;

```
           f'(x) = (dx/dx)sin(x^2)/x   - (d.0/dx) sinx.(0/0)
           f'(x) = 1.sin(x^2)/x -0
           f'(x) = sinx^2/x
```

Is my answer is correct or not . i would be more thankful who rectifying my mistakes ....

Comment: but the answer is 2sin(x^2)/x ,,,i don't know how 2 has come @ my glasses

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what you have done.

HINT :
$$f(x)  = \int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{\sin(xy)}{y}~dy$$
$$f'(x)  = \left[\dfrac{\sin(xy)}{y}\right]_{\text{for } y=x} +\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{\frac{d}{dx}\sin(xy)}{y}~dy$$
$$f'(x)  = \dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x} +\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{y\cos(xy)}{y}~dy$$
$$f'(x)  = \dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x} +\int_{0}^{x}\cos(xy)~dy$$
I suppose that you can take it from here.

Comment: thanks i got the answer 2 sinx^2/ x but,,,im not getting the  second lines of ur answer@  JJacquelin

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If you consider $$f(x)=\int_0^x g(x,y)\,dy$$ the fundamental theorem of calculus would give $$f(x)=g(x,x)+\int_0^x \frac{dg(x,y)}{dx} \,dy$$

Comment: thanks @ Claude leibovici